# How to make a button become invisible but still be able to click?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a button become invisible but still be able to click.

Because I'm using my HTML code with adobe dreamweaver and I dont want to use this ugly standard button so I draw all of my program and pick this button to where I already draw "button"

but after I set this button to invisible so I will going to click on the picture instead........it cant be click :(

really need help

furthermore 1.how to change button size. I want it to be a lot bigger.
            2. how to change input box size. I want it to be a lot bigger too.

Thank you for all help and sorry for my bad grammar that might confuse you.

This is my button

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate!" onClick="useif()" /> <span id="show">Output here</span>
```

Comment: Use `opacity` to make your button transparent.

Comment: use absolute div with button ``width and height`` .

Comment: sorry..I'm really newbie could you please write it in example code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [jsfidder](http://jsfiddle.net/ke0n7r98/) for button invisible but stil able to click on button, PLease click on left top cornor in result

Here is code for html: `<button style="opacity: 0; width:100px; height:100px;">OK</button>`

js function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        alert('ok button clicked');
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following css to your button:

```
.invisible-btn {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

or

```
<input type="button" style="opacity:0" value="Calculate!" onClick="useif()" /> <span id="show">Output here</span>
```

and you can set the size of your element by `width` and `height` properties.

Comment: I'm trying on your second way but after use it..the button integrate with <span>

can you please edit it with my code
    <input type="button" value="Calculate!" onClick="useif()" /> <span id="show">Output here</span>

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<a href="google.com" style="color:white;"><input type="button" hidden="hidden">&nbsp;</input></a>
```

color must be the same as background and you could change cursor type.

Comment: Don't close `</button>` if you'd open `<input>`! Your sample is wrong!